# Approximating Binomial distribution by Poisson distribution when the number of successes is large

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I've been trying to understand when the Binomial distribution can be approximated by the Poisson distribution.

So the Binomial random variable with parameters $(n,p)$ is given by the following probability mass function:

$p(k)=\binom{n}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}$, $k=0,1,2,...,n$

And the Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda$ has probability mass function:

$q(k)=\frac{\lambda^{k}\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda}}{k!}$, $k=0,1,2,...$

Then the Poisson limit theorem states that if $n\rightarrow\infty$, $p\rightarrow0$ and $np=\lambda$, then for every $k\leqslant n$ $p(k)\rightarrow q(k)$

Proof of the theorem from its [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_limit_theorem):

> If we make the stronger assumption $np=\lambda$ (rather than $ np\rightarrow \lambda $) then a simpler proof is possible without needing approximations for the factorials. Since $np=\lambda$, we can rewrite $p=\lambda / n$. We now have:
>   : $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!} \left(\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^k  \left(1- \frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{n-k}
> = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\dots(n-k+1)}{k!} \frac{\lambda^k}{n^k}  \left(1- \frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{n-k} $
>
> Taking each of these terms in sequence, $n(n-1)(n-2)\dots(n-k+1)=n^k+O\left(n^{k-1}\right)$, meaning that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\dots(n-k+1)}{n^k k!}= \frac{1}{k!}$.
>
> Now $\left(1- \frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{n-k}=\left(1- \frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{n}\left(1- \frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{-k}$. The first portion of this converges to $e^{-\lambda}$, and the second portion goes to 1, as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1- \frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{-k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1- 0\right)^{-k}=1$
>
> This leaves us with $\frac{1}{k!}\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}$. Q.E.D.

However, looking at this

> Taking each of these terms in sequence, $n(n-1)(n-2)\dots(n-k+1)=n^k+O\left(n^{k-1}\right)$, meaning that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\dots(n-k+1)}{n^k k!}= \frac{1}{k!}$.

and this

> Now $\left(1- \frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{n-k}=\left(1- \frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{n}\left(1- \frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{-k}$. The first portion of this converges to $e^{-\lambda}$, and the second portion goes to 1, as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1- \frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{-k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1- 0\right)^{-k}=1$

part of the proof, I think we are assuming that in practice, as $k$ is a fixed value while $n\rightarrow\infty$, $k$ must be really small with respect to $n$.

But in practical applications of the theorem, I don't see any mention of that. It seems that you're allowed to use this approximation for any $k$, even if $k=n$, as long as $n$ is large, $p$ is small, and $np$ is moderate. Is there any explanation for this that I don't see?

Comment: It is for fixed $k$ smallish in comparison with $n$.  For larger $k$, the approximation is not bad since both a small, but *relatively* the tail fit is not good.

Comment: You are welcome.